# SQLite many to many join and group

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is a very normal setup for many-to-many relational tables.

1. `product` list and `category` list.
2. Each `product` belongs to `(0,n)` `category`.
3. Each `category` contains `(0,n)` `product`.

### TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE category (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE product_category (
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

### PRODUCT table

```
| id | name |
=============
| 1  |  p1  |
| 2  |  p2  |
| 3  |  p3  |
```

### CATEGORY table

```
| id | name |
=============
| 1  |  c1  |
| 2  |  c2  |
| 3  |  c3  |
```

### PRODUCT_CATEGORY table

```
| product_id | category_id |
============================
|     1      |      1      |
|     1      |      2      |
|     1      |      3      |
|     2      |      1      |
|     2      |      2      |
|     3      |      1      |
```

### Question

I would like to know how to query for `product` by `category_id` and have the `product` listed with all `category_id` that it is in.

For example, I want to query the list of **products** that are available in **category = 1**, and the result must contain a `categories_id` where all categories that the `product` belongs to must be listed.

### Expected output

```
| product_id | product_name | categories_id |
=============================================
|     1      |      p1      |     1,2,3     |
|     2      |      p2      |     1,2       |
|     3      |      p3      |     1         |
```

### Attempts

I know this can be done with sub query, but I would like to know whether this can be achieved by `JOIN` statement?

I have tried the following query but the results does not reflect what I want.

### JOIN QUERY statement

```
SELECT
    P.id AS product_id,
    P.name AS product_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.category_id, ',') AS categories_id
        FROM product AS P
            LEFT JOIN product_category AS PC
                ON P.id = PC.product_id
        WHERE PC.category_id = 1
        GROUP BY P.id;
```

### Output (not as intended)

```
| product_id | product_name | categories_id |
=============================================
|     1      |      p1      |     1         |
|     2      |      p2      |     1         |
|     3      |      p3      |     1         |
```

Can anyone advice on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1c20/6/0) for the execution and query is

```
SELECT P.id AS product_id, P.name AS product_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(PC2.category_id) AS categories_id
FROM 
product AS P LEFT JOIN product_category AS PC ON 
P.id = PC.product_id LEFT JOIN product_category AS PC2 ON 
P.id = PC2.product_id
WHERE PC.category_id = 1
GROUP BY P.id;
```

Comment: Works nice! Before I accept the answer, can you please explain why double `JOIN` to `product_category` is required here?

Comment: First join is to identify the products for category_id = 1 and second join is to identify all the categories, product found in first join is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pc2.category_id, ',')
        FROM product_category pc1
            JOIN product_category pc2
            JOIN product p
        WHERE pc1.category_id = 1
            AND pc1.product_id = pc2.product_id
            AND p.id = pc1.product_id
        GROUP BY pc1.product_id;
```

Comment: This seems to generate weird output (eg. `1,,2,,3,`)?

Comment: You may get that weird output with `MySQL`, but it works properly with `SQLite`.